# Can providers be configured later then app config time?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to configure a provider at any give time or they can be only configured at app config time?

Thanks.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Although most things which can be configured during the app config time can also be configured later (just not as providers). Consider the $http service as an example, you can actually still set default headers, etc even out of the config, just using the $http service instead of $httpProvider. Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS*:

> Providers can be configured only during the configuration (first) phase. Surely, it
>   doesn't make sense to change a recipe after objects are baked, right?

Comment: Thanks. And it does make sense if `the cake doesn't have all the ingredients yet` to be inline with the analogy from the book.